# datatables replaces 2+spaces with one space + can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```html
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger          Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
```

I noticed that datatables removes 2+ spaces and replaces it with 1 space in the data that is fed into datatables. This can be seen in `<td>Tiger          Nixon</td>` above. So in the datatables it appears as `Tiger Nixon`(with one space).So I can find `Tiger          Nixon` with by searching for`Tiger Nixon`(with one space).As a silly example, what if I wanted to find `Tiger          Nixon` with all the spaces in `Tiger Nixon`(with one space).

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7bLat1ph/) that illustrates this.

This is more an observation that I just discovered, but I would be interested to know if there was a way to stop datatables doing it. So that the data exactly as it is passed to datables.

**NOTE** As an aside I have another datatables example that uses [serverside processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) and datatables leaves the 2+spaces as is, but I cannot illustrate that here.

Furher to this NOTE:

If I search in the db with 2 spaces

```
select * from xyz23 where Device_Manufacturer LIKE '%International  %';
                                                                  ^^2spaces
```

It will bring back the 4 results with 2 spaces

```
International  Telecommunications Investment and Commerce Joint Stock Company 
             ^^2spaces
```

Searching for this in datatables:

```
International  
             ^^2spaces
```

Will bring back the 4 results but they will only have 1 space in the datatable:

```
International Telecommunications Investment and Commerce Joint Stock Company
             ^1space
```

Even though 2 spaces are returned from the db (seen in the response under Network-XHR-Response in chrome)

```
International  Telecommunications Investment and Commerce Joint Stock Company
             ^^2spaces
```

But this makes sense based on @davidkonrad answers below "...simply how HTML is intended to be rendered...", even though it threw me a bit before understanding this.

However, if I search in datatables for:

```
International T
             ^1space
```

I will get no results, which is different to what it shows when it does find it using 2 spaces below.

but if I search in datatables for:

```
International  T
             ^^2spaces
```

I get the 4 results with 1 space:

```
International Telecommunications Investment and Commerce Joint Stock Company
             ^1space
```

So it can be a bit confusing, but I understand it better now and thanks to @davidkonrad for his way around this below

---

### EDIT1 - for my reference

to just do it on the 1st column: use `targets: 0,`

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs : [{
    targets: 0,
    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
       return '<pre>' + data + '</pre>'
    }
  }]

});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is totally expected. It is not dataTables that "replaces" whitespace but simply how HTML is intended to be rendered by a reader / browser. Whitespace is supposed to be left our or reduced to the absolute minimum.

If you want to preserve the blanks you could wrap the content into a `<pre>` section, like this :

```js
columnDefs : [{
   targets: '_all',
   render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
     return '<pre>' + data + '</pre>'
   }
}]
```

Now whitespaces is preserved in all columns. If the default browser rendering of the `<pre>` tag is a concern you can reset it so it seems transparent :

```css
pre {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}
```

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/7bLat1ph/1/** try search for "tiger" ..

---

**Update**. Example of a custom filter that respects blanks.

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function( settings, data, dataIndex ) { 
  var term = $('.dataTables_filter input').val().replace(/\s/, '&nbsp;');
  if (!term) return true;
  for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (~data[i].replace(/\s/, '&nbsp;').indexOf(term)) return true
  }
  return false
})
```

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/7bLat1ph/2/**

Comment: tks excellent answer. I added a "Further to my note" in the question which you heloed me to get to. If you would, although not entirely necessary, care to comment/confirm that i have it right.

Comment: @HattrickNZ, I see your point. You are right. You would need a custom filter to do what you need. See updated fiddle / answer. I am not so skilled in regexes so I have just made a stupid `' '` replacement to  `&nbsp;`. Try search for `'  '` in the updated fiddle.